# Makefile getting all object files in a directory

Tags: c++, makefile, googletest, object-files

I currently have a C++ google test project that relies on another program to be built first. In my google test test project makefile I am trying to get all the object files in the project it is testing. So for example:

```
USER_OBJS = $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/class1.o
USER_OBJS = $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/class2.o
USER_OBJS = $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/class3.o
```

However, whenever there is a class added or removed to the project that is being tested, then I have to manually change USER_OBJS in my makefile. With automated testing, this is becoming a hassle. Does anyone know how I can make USER_OBJS just get all the object files in the tested project? I have tried the following:

```
USER_OBJS := $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/$(wildcard *.o)
```

Still does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: The first lines are missing `+=` so they don't work as intended but that's neither here nor there. Move the path variable *into* the wildcard so make can actually perform the correct glob. That being said that won't help if this makefile needs to *build* those `.o` files since they won't exist when `make` is run. In which case you need to get that list from the *source* files that build them instead.

Comment: I forgot to add the += on the lines above. If I move the path into the wildcard would it be the following: USER_OBJS := $($PATH/wildcard *.o)   ??

Comment: You tell me. Is that where a path on the glob would go? Which part of `wildcard` and `*.o` are you modifying with the path variable (note: not `$PATH` your `$(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)` variable)?

Comment: I am not quite sure where the path would go. I am new to the wildcard expression and I am having trouble finding any help on it. I have tried a few different ways. This is the way I thought it should go: USER_OBJS := $($(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/*.o)    I have also tried $($(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/wildcard *.o)

Comment: The first try there lost the `wildcard` bit but got the variable location right. The second try got the variable location very wrong. The [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) (specifically the entry on [The Function `wildcard`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function)) would probably be a good place to start looking for help on it. That being said it just takes a glob/pattern and expands it.

Comment: I did USER_OBJS = $(wildcard $(TEST_TARGET_PATH:=/*.o)) and that seemed to fix the problem. Now I have run into another issue. If I found out that this did not infact fix the problem then I will post on here. Thanks for your help Etan!

Comment: Not quite. You want `USER_OBJS := $(wildcard $(TEST_TARGET_PATH)/*.o)`. What you have works but is odd and unnecessary.

Comment: When I used USER_OBJS := $(wildcard $(TEST_TARGET_PATH)/*.o) it did not work. The USER_OBJS = $(wildcard $(TEST_TARGET_PATH:=/*.o)) seems to work correctly in my case. Since my project has a main() and the project being tested had a main() as well, I had to remove the .o file with the main() (the object file in the project being tested) from the list. I used the command USER_OBJS := $(filter-out $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/class1.o, $(USER_OBJS)) I am just throwing this extra information out there for anyone who runs into the same problem I did.

Comment: What happened with the version I suggested? It should be exactly identical to your version (unless `$(TEST_TARGET_PATH)` has multiple paths in it). The `$(var:=)` syntax is a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) and used the way you did is identical to `$(patsubst %,%/*.o,$(TEST_TARGET_PATH))` which is the same as appending `/*.o` to `$(TEST_TARGET_PATH)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want (class1.o, class2.o, class3.o), use…

```
USER_OBJS = $(wildcard $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/class[1-3].o)
```

If you want all object files, use…

```
USER_OBJS = $(wildcard $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/*.o)
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way to use "wildcard" in your case should be:

```
USER_OBJS = $(wildcard $(PROJECT_BEING_TESTED_PATH)/*.o)
```